# memcpy mixing up contents of struct?

Tags: c, file, io, memcpy

I've been working with writing to R2K object modules, and I've been having trouble writing the symbol table entries to the file. I've been attempting to use memcpy to put the entries of the symbol table, stored in sym_table, into an array of one byte integers called bytes_sym, which is then written to the file. It copies the correct sizes, but jumbles up the placement of the bytes for some reason. Here is my code:

```
/*
** symbol table entry
*/    
typedef
struct syment {
    uint32_t flags;      /* flag word */
    uint32_t value;      /* value associated with this symbol */
    uint32_t sym;        /* symbol name's index into string table */
}
    syment_t;

// header->data[8] is the number of symbol table entries
int sym_length = header->data[8] * sizeof(syment_t);

uint8_t bytes_sym[sym_length];

for(int i = 0; i < header->data[8]; i++){
    memcpy(&bytes_sym[i * sizeof(syment_t)], &sym_table[i], sizeof(syment_t));
}
fwrite(bytes_sym, sym_length, 1, file);

// prints the newly copied symbol table section one byte at a time
// I know it's gross to look at, but it's only for testing :p
printf("New Symtab:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < sym_length; i++){
    printf("0x%x ", bytes_sym[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

before writing, the bytes values are:

```
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xb1 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x2c 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa3 0x10 0x0 0x0 0x20 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x5
0x0 0x0 0x40 0xb1 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x38 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xb
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa1 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x14 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10
0x0 0x0 0x40 0xb1 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x15
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x67 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x11 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1f
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xa2 0x10 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x19
0x0 0x0 0x40 0xb1 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x64 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x29
```

after writing, they are (incorrect, shouldn't be different):

```
0xb1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2c 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xa3 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x20 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x5 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xb1 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x38 0x0 0x40 0x0 0xb 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xa1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x14 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x10 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xb1 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x15 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0x67 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x11 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1f 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xa2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x19 0x0 0x0 0x0 
0xb1 0x40 0x0 0x0 0x64 0x0 0x40 0x0 0x29 0x0 0x0 0x0
```

I just can't wrap my head around what's causing this, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  What do the data structures look like?  We need to know about that.  Please also read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: So you want to look at the code writing and reading the data as well? Also make `0x%x` a `0x%02x`.

Comment: Looks like a big endian vs little endian issue. We need more information,
 especially a [MCVE] would be helpful, but `memcpy` will definitely not mixup anything. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: My understanding is the values are copied properly. It is just the way you are reading them to print is what is causing the issue. Can you show the code for printing before memcopy? Also which one them is the correct one?

Comment: Please compare with a dump of the source data using `for (i = 0; i < header->data[8] * sizeof(syment_t); i++) { printf("0x%x ", *((const uint8_t *)sym_table)[i]); } printf("\n");`

Comment: @IanAbbott That gives me a syntax error: `error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)`

Comment: @alk that is correct

Comment: @MichaelWalz It does appear to be that sort of issue, but I'm having trouble    identifying the cause if it isn't caused by `memcpy`. I have noticed a pattern, however. When copying over the contents using `memcpy`, every 4th byte in the new array is moved back by 3 bytes. In addition, when I use the write command a second time, it puts everything back in the correct position. Is it possible that I'm using `memcpy` incorrectly?

Comment: You'll need to actually provide a [mcve] in order to see for sure, but it seems to be more likely that what is going on is that you are not printing the data consistently.

Answer (score -3):

Alright, you guys totally lied about `memcpy` not messing with my data. After doing a bit of research, I figured out that it was an endian thing that reversed the order of the bytes in each 4 byte block in the symbol table section of my 32 bit object module. So I wrote a little function to fix it:

```
///    Flips the bytes in each 4 byte block after the endian flip caused by memcpy
///    @param - the array of bytes
///    @param - the length of the array in bytes
///
void flip_bytes(uint8_t byte_array[], int length){

    uint8_t tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if((i+1) % 4 == 0){

                    // switch the first and last bytes
                    tmp = byte_array[i];
                    byte_array[i] = byte_array[i-3];
                    byte_array[i-3] = tmp;
                    // switch the middle 2 bytes
                    tmp = byte_array[i-1];
                    byte_array[i-1] = byte_array[i-2];
                    byte_array[i-2] = tmp;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of itself, used correctly, `memcpy()` does not mess anything up. You've not provided enough information for anyone to know what your problem was in the first place; you've not provided enough information in this 'answer' to demonstrate where and how you use this function; your claim about 'totally lied' is out of order. You probably have code which invokes undefined behaviour. It's hard to be sure because you've not provided an [MCVE], but erratic behaviour arises from erratic coding. When used correctly (for example, the source and target areas of memory may not overlap), `memcpy()` works.

Comment: Downvoting this answer, because it is misleading.  It is just plain incorrect to suggest that `memcpy` is endian-aware and writes bytes in a different order to the source.  What you're probably encountering is the source data itself uses a different endianness to what you expect.  This is a data format issue, and nothing to do with `memcpy`.

Comment: You should not take this feedback negatively. If answer contains misinformation, then it can potentially harm future readers, and it should be pointed out.